# File uploads from multiple clients slowing Java Spring application

Tags: java, mysql, angularjs, amazon-ec2, spring-boot

I have an application with Java Spring, mysql backend and AngularJS frontend. It's hosted on amazon ec2 m4.xlarge instance.

I use the HTML5 camera capture capability to take photograph and send base64 encoded image and some other metadata to backend via a RESTful web service. At the back-end I convert the base64 data to a png file and save to disk and also make an entry to MySQL database about the status of the file. This has been working fine until many users start uploading images at the same time. There are 4000+ users in the system and at the peak there could be around 1000 concurrent users trying to upload image data simultaneously. Having too many users slows down my application and it take 10-15 seconds to return any page (normally its under 2 seconds). I checked my server stats and the CPU utilization is under 20%, and no SWAP memory is used. I am not sure where the bottleneck is and how to measure it. Any suggestion on how to approach the problem? I know that autoscaling ec2 and having queue in image data processing at the backend might help, but before doing anything I want to get to the root cause of the problem.

Java code to process base64 image:

```
/**
 * POST  /rest/upload/studentImage -> Upload a photo of the user and update the Student (Student History and System Logs)
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/upload/studentImage",
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    produces = "application/json")
@Timed
public Integer create(@RequestBody StudentPhotoDTO studentPhotoDTO) {
    log.debug("REST request to save Student : {}", studentPhotoDTO);
    Boolean success = false;
    Integer returnValue = 0;

    final String baseDirectory = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/studentPhotos/";

    Long studentId = studentPhotoDTO.getStudent().getStudentId();

    String base64Image = studentPhotoDTO.getImageData().split(",")[1];
    byte[] imageBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64Image);
    try {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes));

        String filePath = baseDirectory + 'somestring';
        log.info("Saving uploaded file to: " + filePath);

        File f = new File(filePath);
        Boolean bool = f.mkdirs();

        File outputfile = new File(filePath + studentId + ".png");
        success = ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        success = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(Exception ex){
        success = false;
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(success) {
        returnValue = 1;
        // update student
        studentPhotoDTO.getStudent().setPhotoAvailable(true);
        studentPhotoDTO.getStudent().setModifiedOn(new Date());

        studentRepository.save(studentPhotoDTO.getStudent());
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Here is an image of my cloudwatch network monitoring

[image: Network In]

Update (06/17/2015):

I am serving the Spring Boot tomcat application with apache fronting using ajp ProxyPass. I tried to directly serve the tomcat app without the apache fronting and that seem to significantly improve the performance. My app didn't slow down as before. Still looking for the root cause.

Comment: Have you checked the raw network throughput available to your VM?

Comment: I haven't tested myself, but aws documentation says Dedicated EBS
Throughput 750 Mbps. For my app the base64 images are around 100kb each so even if 1000 users simultaneously try to upload it will be like 100Mb at max. Or I am I missing something here? I just added a screenshot of cloudwatch monitoring.

Comment: Not EBS, the incoming Internet connection.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted. I could use some help on how to measure that. AWS says High, but for the exact value, I would probably need to use some tool I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a technical approach to solve this problem, I would recommend having a good design that takes care of this problem. In my opinion, which is used totally based on the information that you have provided, I think its a design problem. To find the root cause of this problem, I need to have a look at your code.

But as of now, a design should be to use a queue that processes images at the back end, and at the front end, notifies the user that their image has been queued to process. Once its processed, it should say that it has been processed (or not processed because of some error).

If you can show code, I can try to figure out the problem if there is any.

Comment: I agree. It's most likely a design problem only, and the implementation was wrong to begin with due to time crunch. I was thinking of having a queue mechanism, but didn't reach there. I have pasted the code that takes care of the back end base64 blob to image file processing.  Please let me know if you have any comments. Thanks!